# increment the duplicate value of object in any array of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a 5 age fields  where user can enter same value they are not validating 
while sending to the API. I have to increment the duplicate ages in ech object.

for ex - if user gives ages like 10, 11, 10, 10, 20 i need it as 10,11,12,13,20 like this

**Here is the variable having duplicate:**

```
var family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt"
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 22
  }
];
```

where every duplicate values comes i have to increment by checking all the ages in each object i need out put like this --> here age 13 and 22 is duplicating i have to check all ages and i have to increment 2nd repeted age by +1 -->

```
var family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt"
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 24
  }
];
```

**note my array will have only 5 objects**

Comment: @Nick this question looks nice... he want to increase age only if they are same.. can you open it?

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib i think it will work let me check all the scenario's

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib as of now its working great thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code. Hope this will be help u.

```
var family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 22
  }
];
var ind = [];
family.forEach(a => {
  cur = a.age;
  while (ind[cur] === 1) {
     cur++;
  }
  ind[cur] = 1;
  a.age = cur;
});
family.forEach(a => console.log(a.age));
```

Comment: i think it will work let me check all the scenario's

Comment: as of now its working great thank you @golamMazidSajib

Answer (score 0):

Another update:

```
var order = family.map((person, index) => {
  return { index, person };
  }).sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.person.age === b.person.age) {
         return a.index - b.index;
      }
      return a.person.age > b.person.age ? 1 : -1;
  });

var prevAge = 0;
order.forEach(item => {
  if (item.person.age <= prevAge) {
    item.person.age = ++prevAge;
  }
  prevAge = item.person.age;
  family.filter(f => f.name === item.person.name)[0].age = item.person.age;
});
```

Please, try the different cases I put in the demo and check if the results are what you would expect.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-far3zq

Comment: its not working for few  Scenario's like this var family =  [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 15
  }
];
output has to come like this ->  [ { name: "Mike",age: 10}, {name: "Matt", age: 11},{name:"Nancy", age: 20 },{name: "Adam", age: 14 },{name: "Jenny",age: 15}];
but its coming  [ {name: "Mike",age: 10 },{  name: "Matt", age: 11 }, { name: "Nancy",age: 20 }, name: "Adam", age: 21 },{name:"Jenny",age: 22  }]; @kari

Comment: new changes is not working for diff diff cases bro, user can enter min 10 there no max value, if he wnters like 10,10,10,20,14 expected o/p -> 10,11,12,20,14 but new changes  is not working

Comment: not working i think u didn't get the scenario properly

Comment: Well, it's working for the three cases you described in your question and your comments. In which other scenario it doesn't work?

Comment: For example, if the input is 15, 14, 14, 13, 13 what would be the expected output?

Comment: 15,14,16,13,17 is the expected output @kari

Comment: let me explain the scenario: here user can enter any 5 values for the age: our case is to check if the duplicate age is there if it is there increment that  duplicate  value and if the user enters the incremented value in the age this value again has to be  incremented ex: user I/p 10,10,11,12,10  o/p -> 10,11,12,13,14 like this here 2nd we are incrementing that value is already entered by user then we have increase that by +1 same for all, i think u got the scenario ryt?